# React Virtualized Lists - Is the height prop referring to the height of the entire list or is it the height of the scrollable area?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a modal formatted like so:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-ardinghelli-s3u65l?file=/src/App.js:222-1044

And after reading a few articles on virtualized lists, I was confused as to what the height prop was referring to in this code snippet from a tutorial:

```
<List
width={rowWidth}
height={listHeight}
rowHeight={rowHeight}
rowRenderer={this.renderRow}
rowCount={this.list.length} />
```

In the case of my layout, is the height of the list the height of the scrolling area or of my list itself? Because initially my list starts off with fewer items visible than when you start scrolling towards the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [documentation](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md)

> Height constraint for list (determines how many actual rows are rendered)

In other words, it defines the scrollable area. The library will use the `rowCount` and `rowHeight` props to define how big the list is.

Comment: For the list height though, if it's dependent on the dynamic row heights, how do we set that? (I don't think setting it to a fixed number would work..) @Koronag

Comment: If your row heights are dynamic, the `rowHeight` prop also takes a function, you can then define the `rowHeight` for each individual row.

And if you wish to change the `height` of the list when row heights changes, you could easily do that using `useState`.

Comment: But what if I don't know the list height ahead of time? (It seems like the List element requires a height prop) Would you happen to have an example of using state to get the height? (I was able to use CellMeasurer to get dynamic row heights) I also found a method called `measureAllRows` that seemed helpful... @Koronag

Comment: I made a working example of a hacky workaround that I found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-gagarin-vczki1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think you might overthink this. The height indicates the height of the element, and that again decides how many rows can be displayed. You should determine the height of the element the same way you would determine any element on a page. Just want it to take up 500px? Then set 500px. Want it to take up 70vh? Then calculate that based on the window height and set it in pixels.

Comment: Hm, the issue that I’m having is that my list item has no set height; basically it’s not always a fixed amount of list items that will appear (I.e. it will behave like a list of search results so sometimes it could be 5 items, and other times it may be 100 items) So the height of the list varies depending on how many list items show up

Comment: So let's say that you don't want this list to be longer than 600px, think of this is a CSS `max-height`. But if there are only 5 rows, and each of them takes up `50px` then you just want the element to take up the needed height in the DOM. You could do a a ternary condition for example `height={5 * 50 < 600 ? 5 * 50 : 600}` . This is just an example though, so you could also calculate this in a separate function if you wish.

Comment: Hmm, what if the list has no max height and the rows have varying heights? (I found that using CellMeasurer could account for dynamic row heights but not sure how to get a list height..) In that case the row multiplier technique probably won’t work too well

Comment: Why would you need a virtualized list if the list has no max height? The intention with the virtualized list is to just render a subset of the elements to the DOM, and render more as the user scrolls. Rows having varying heights could be taken account for in a separate functions that iterates over the rows and calculates their total height to see if it crosses the `max-height` (listHeight) value or not.

Comment: I need a virtualized list for performance reasons. I don’t have a max height but I do have a min height…is there a way to do something similar with that and dynamic row heights?

Comment: Hmm...I think I'm almost at my final workaround: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-saha-so14wh?file=/src/App.js, what I can't figure out is how to tell the list to remeasure the cached row heights when switching in between list lengths though...

Comment: I'll try to explain this as well as I can, the `height` property indicates how many rows you want to render at a time, to increase performance.

What you are doing:
Setting the height to 3540px, basically rendering the whole list (30 rows) and not gaining any improvement in performance. You are doing the same thing as just rendering the list outside the virtual list would do.

What you should do:
Set the height to only show a subset of the rows (590px for example, so you only render 5 rows at a time), and then render the rows as the user scrolls.

Comment: Ah I think I understand, I think…putting this list in the modal and trying to fit the modal scrolling behavior is complicating things :/ Is there a way to achieve what you’re describing while keeping the same scrolling behavior as my sandbox??

Comment: (i.e. is there a way to not have that inner scroll bar on the list card? It seems that giving it a height of 590px for example produces that inner scroll; instead, is there a way to have the scrolling only on the content modal itself?) I tried using `WindowScroller`, but I think the overflow styling on the modal messes things up

Comment: Looks that it would be possible utilizing the `scrollTop` prop. Take a look at the WindowScroller component on how it could be implemented:
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/WindowScroller.md

That component listens to the scroll event on the window though, so it's not exactly what you want. But you could get some ideas.

Comment: Oh huh, I see that WindowScroller has something called `scrollElement`, perhaps I can use that to tell it that the element being scrolled is my modal and not the window? Kinda like this (except right now it doesn't seem to work): https://codesandbox.io/s/lrqsgy?file=/src/App.js. If possible, do you think you could see if there's any tweaks I need in my sandbox? It's been hard to find documentation/examples on this prop specifically :/

Comment: Aha, seems like someone else had this use case, which prompted the creation of the `scrollElement` prop: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/474. Unfortunately still no documented examples of actually using this prop though...

Comment: (Since these comments are getting long and it's diverged from my original post, I made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72004845/react-virtualized-how-to-use-the-scrollelement-prop-from-windowscroller)